# C#: Find all empty catch blocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am reviewing some code.

I have notice some empty catch blocks. Not a good idea since somethings do not work and you cannot see why.

Is there an easy way to find all empty try catch blocks in a solution?

Comment: Just an FYI - not all empty catch blocks are bad.  Sometimes, the developer is catching for a specific exception precisely so that the exception can be ignored.

Comment: @Matt, Thanks, agree with you, but then we have a rule that the developer must put a comment in to confirm that it is done with intent.

Comment: @Matt - but catch(Exception) is almost always bad.

Comment: could you post your variations here? I'm intrestet in this topic too, but not in regex ;-)

Comment: Also as an FYI - Sometimes libraries will allow for callouts to user functions.  Empty 'Catch' statements are the only way to prevent these user-supplied functions, which can throw any exception, from terminating the remaining processes in the library.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use use the global find dialog, turn on regular expressions and then search for:

```
catch:b*\([^)]*\):b*\{:b*\}
```

Comment: FxCop or ReSharper would be overkill for just empty try/catch, good thinking!

Comment: The answer above did not work for me, but this did "catch(\(.*Exception.*\))*:Wh*\{:Wh*\}" without the quotes.

Comment: Yeah. This answer doesn't actually match empty catches... @Ghost's works though.

Comment: The answer will only work if the catch block has nothing, but what about the catch blocks contain only commented-out code/s?

Comment: The Regex didn't work for me unless I replaced `:b` by `\s`. (VS 2017)

Answer (score 15):

Expanded the accepted answer to satisfy all the conditions described below. 
Updated for Visual Studio 2017/2019, works for both C# and C++.

**Use the find dialog (CTRL+SHIFT+F), turn on regular expressions and search for:**

```
^(?!\/\/|\/\*).*catch\s*(?:\([^)]*\))*\s*\{\s*(?:(?:\/\/|\/\*).*(\*\/)?\s*)*\}
```

**Matches:**

```
catch {}
catch{}
catch{
}
catch 
{}
catch () {}
catch (...) {}
catch (int x) {}
catch (Exception x) {}
catch (Exception ex){
}
catch(...){
}
} catch (...){
/**/
}
} catch (...){
/**/
///
}
} catch (...){
//
//
/**/
}
catch (...)
{}
catch(...) { //single line
}
catch(...) { 
//single line}
catch(...) { 
//single line
}
catch(...) { /*multiline*/
}
catch(...) {
 /*multiline*/}
catch(...) {
 /*multiline*/
}
catch (...){ // int i = 0; }
```

**Does not match:**

```
// catch () {}
/* catch () {} */
catch (...){ int i = 0;}
catch (...){ 
int i = 0;}
catch (...){int i = 0;
}
catch (...){ 
// Comment
int i = 0;}
catch (...){ int i = 0; // Comment}
```

Comment: Malformed expression, at least in vs 2017

Comment: Thanks @jjxtra, I've updated the answer to work on more modern VS versions. Also detailing the conditions it matches/doesn't match.

Comment: That's very nice of you, most people wouldn't care to take the time

Answer (score 7):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) will find them along with many other potential issues.

Comment: Can you name the rule that catches empty catch blocks?

Answer (score 6):

Do you have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)? This should hilight the issues found in code.

Comment: I haven't found where or how to this in ReSharper... how would you do it?

Comment: It shows up as a warning with ReSharper, but I think you have to have the code file open to see it.

Comment: Oddly enough, I found one of these in some code the other day. We use both FxCop and ReSharper; someone had explicitly suppressed the FxCop warning (so it didn't show up on the Continuous Integration build) and ignored the ReSharper one. Not much you can do about that. :P

Comment: As to finding them in the build - yes, there are ways to suppress them explicitly, but they'd better have a very good reason for doing so.  They're hard to find without a detailed code review, though.  I'm in the process of doing such a review, and finding these guys with the regex from Sverrir has been a big help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regular expression that finds also catch blocks with only comments inside :

```
catch:b*\([^)]*\)[:b\n]*\{([:b\n]|(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(//[^\n]*))*\}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Stefan for the Regex suggestion. I found that the suggested regex does not find catch blocks where the exception is not specified, ie:

```
catch { }
```

I tweaked Stefan's slightly to make the exception brace optional:

```
catch:b*(\([^)]*\))*:b*\{:b*\}
```

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Shift + F. 
Expand Find options. 
Check Use Regular Expressions 
Paste this regex.

```
catch\s*(\(\s*Exception(\s*\w+)?\))?\s*\{\s*\}
```

Comment: I added the details to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @bobah75 's answer, it wouldn't recognize this line

```
catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException ex)
{
}
```

So to fix that, here is the solution

```
catch\s*(\(?.+Exception(\s*\w+)?\))?\s*\{\s*([:b\n]|(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(//[^\n]*))*\}
```

you can test it out [here](http://regexr.com/42do0)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would suggest using [Sonar Analyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/7.13.0.8313). You can add it via NuGet manager in Visual Studio.

It will show all unused catch blocks and also show you a tip what do do with it, something in lines of: "Implement or comment why empty."

Also, it will show you a lot more of possible code issues.

Answer (score 0):

catch\s*((?.+Exception(\s*\w+)?))?\s*{\s*([:b\n]|(/*[^*]**/)|(//[^\n]*))*}

Visual Studio 2022. Only This expression is actually working.