# How to find an ignored exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Probably staying late fixing a few bugs tonight, but maybe SO can help me out. Does anyone know if there's a way to 'track' where some ignored exceptions are occurring?

Basically I'm finding some System.OverflowExceptions in System.Drawing which are causing some graphics to not get painted (red X box syndrome).

Problem is, I can only tell this from the Debug window, and can not for the life of me find where this is being thrown. I'm guessing the coder of where this is happening wrote a

try{ something } finally { blah }

or...

try {something } catch { //Blah blah blah }

If I'm SOL as far as that goes, maybe somebody might know what methods in System.Drawing may cause a StackOverflow excption...

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that should read OverflowException in the last sentence ;)

Comment: Did you try configuring the debugger to break when this specific exception is thrown? Debug -> Exceptions... -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> System.OverflowException

Comment: Oh sweet, I didn't know you could do that. You should make that an answer, divo, so I can vote you up!

Comment: Agreed, divo you are my hero... fixed and going home 18 minutes after asking the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure the debugger to break on an exception even if it has been handled.

You can configure the behavior via *Debug -> Exceptions...*. In your specific case you should check *Debug -> Exceptions... -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> System.OverflowException*:

[image]
<sub>(source: [scatterbright.com](http://scatterbright.com/debug-exceptions.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx)/[StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) to get [what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486424/c-find-all-empty-catch-blocks).  I'm not sure if you would need a [custom](http://mystuffisallhere.com/blog/post/2006/01/02/An-FxCop-rule-to-detect-swallowed-exceptions.aspx) [rule](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/45c379fd-4953-4618-a05e-f36d6ab6c1fe) to find your try/finally scenario.